# Installing Scala Language on MacBook : Manually (No Brew or Coursier)

Tags: scala, homebrew, coursier

I am trying to install scala language on my work laptop (mac). Could someone let me know the installation commands if I am unable to use brew or coursier? I have downloaded the package from github directly but unsure of next steps.

When using courier download as given on scala website I get this error:
Checking if the standard Scala applications are installed:
Exception in thread "main" coursier.error.ResolutionError$CantDownloadModule: Error downloading io.get-coursier:apps:latest.release

I have a feeling that my works security does not allow this installation. Is there a way around it / manual install for scala?

Homebrew I cannot download as I am not allowed to give out passwords during installation.

Comment: Can you use **sdkman**? If not, then not worry about **Scala** and rather just install **sbt** or **scala-cli** directly... but, I would guess you will find more security errors along the way in any case.

Comment: How do you install sbt?

Comment: I think you already got help in the **Discord** server, right? Were you able to solve the issue?

Answer (score 3):

You can try the command listed on their [site](https://www.scala-lang.org/download/) for the Mac installation:

```
curl -fL https://github.com/coursier/launchers/raw/master/cs-x86_64-apple-darwin.gz | gzip -d > cs && chmod +x cs && (xattr -d com.apple.quarantine cs || true) && ./cs setup
```

This should do everything on its own.

However, if you have admin rights, I recommend installing it via `brew`. Using `brew` is the most popular and easiest way, and you will use `brew` a lot on the Mac:

```
brew update
brew install scala
```

If you are not allowed to have admin rights, go to your IT department and have them install Scala for you via the `brew` command.

If this is not possible, you can simply download the Scala binaries. For example, assuming you want Scala 2.13.10, just download and unzip the  [scala-2.13.10.tgz](https://downloads.lightbend.com/scala/2.13.10/scala-2.13.10.tgz) zip file at your desired location. After that, you will have to set up your `PATH` manually, to be able to use the `scala` command in the command line:

```
export PATH=”/Users/your_user/scala/bin:$PATH”
```

Here's a more detailed [tutorial](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/scala-setup-on-mac-os.html) on this approach.